# Will #2 aluminum provide 50 amps at 700 ft?

Tags: electrical

I have #2 aluminum already at 600 ft I need to go another 100 ft and have 50 amps.

Comment: So long as you don't mind huge voltage drop, which you already have for 50A @ 600 feet. If you mind huge voltage drop, time for a pair of 15 kVA transformers.

Comment: What voltages are you dealing with?

Comment: Are you in the United States or Canada?

Answer (score 2):

If you're happy with its performance at 600 feet, another 100 feet won't matter.

Voltage drop is decided by *the actual loads* you put on the system, not the value on the breaker handle.  So how bad it will be will depend on what your actual loads are.  It's not 50A - if it were, you'd be having 12% voltage drop and you would not be happy with that situation.

If you plan to increase load or distance further, you will be forced to use transformers to step the voltage up to 480V or 600V, and then step it back down to 120/240V for local use.  Having reliable grounding rods at the RV site will be extra important.

Make splices properly.  Torque screws to specification.

Answer (score 1):

### The Amps are not a problem if you can stand the loss of Volts.

http://www.paigewire.com/wire_resistance-prop.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Gives 0.261 Ohms per 1000 feet at 25°C, 0.319 Ohms per 1000 feet at 75°C

For 600 feet, 0.6*0.261 = .1566 Ohms, 7.83 volts @ 50A

But, it's actually 1200 feet of wire (there and back again,) so 15.66 volts.

19.14 Volts at 75°C

700 feet, is 1400 feet of wire, is 18.27 Volts at 25°C or **22.33 Volts** at 75°C

The 75°C are better for design purposes, as you will be heating the wire with something in the ballpark of 1000 watts.

Whether your application can stand that much voltage drop or not is unknown, since it's unspecified. Some electrical loads are pickier than others about the voltage supplied. Many US "240V" loads will also work on 208V, at reduced power. Others will object, or not work well-enough. You'd appear to be in the ballpark of 218 volts delivered if your supply is 240V.